# What is the difference between 'flonum?' and '##flonum?' in Gambit Scheme?

Tags: scheme, gambit, lambdanative

I see '##flonum?' in the source of the Calculator application in LambdaNative.

Answer (score 0):

The "##" denotes a special namespace - the "internal" code as opposed to user code. So "##flonum?" is an internally-defined function as opposed to "flonum?". One may be more performant than the other.

See http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/wiki/index.php/Namespaces. That page also mentions that this mechanism is not described in official documentation. The Gambit-C v4.7.9 reference has "To Do" in the namespace section.